# Statsig issue with Before Time and After TIme

Tags: reactjs, date, time, statsig

I need to configure Statsig flag to return true for 30 days, by setting from and to dates
I am using "check time and date" and I am trying to set before and after time. But its giving invalid error. Not sure what is the mistake. Please guide to resolve this issue

[image]

Comment: may be it need specific format for setting up data and time

Answer (score 3):

Statsig uses American formats for dates - so MM/DD/YYYY, and XX:XX AM/PM

I think the UI should have a datepicker which enforces this.  Here's what mine looks like

[image: date and time]